# C# Time calculator converting string seconds, to minutes, to hours, to days WITHOUT time span

Tags: c#, string, int, calculation

I am a student extremely confused on this program prompt in which I need to create a program that has an input for the seconds, and when the calculation button is pushed the seconds are displayed along with it's conversion into minutes, hours, and days.

I know my formatting is incorrect, and I've read through my text trying to find something that remotely relates to my program but I am struggling hard to find it.

Can someone explain to me where I'm going wrong and why ?

Again, I'd like to stress that I am still learning C# and haven't gotten to time span yet. So this needs to be in a string conversion as well as in some sort of if-statement.

Please provide an explanation as well because I am wanting to get the hang of this. I also need to have input validation with this, and I've attempted below here.

Here is my code:

```
private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalSeconds, minutes, hours, days;
        int secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
        int secondsInHour = 60 * 60;
        int secondsInMinute = 60;



        if (int.TryParse(secondsInputTextBox.Text, out totalSeconds))

        {
            if (totalSeconds > secondsInDay)
            {
                days = totalSeconds / secondsInDay;
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds - (days * secondsInDay);
                daysTextBox.Text = days.ToString();
            }

            if (totalSeconds > secondsInHour)
            {
                hours = totalSeconds / secondsInHour;
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds - (hours * secondsInHour);
                hoursTextBox.Text = hours.ToString();
            }

            if (totalSeconds > secondsInMinute)
            {
                minutes = totalSeconds / secondsInMinute;
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds - (minutes * secondsInMinute);
                minutesTextBox.Text = minutes.ToString();
            }

            else
            {
                secondsTextBox.Text = totalSeconds.ToString();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect input. Please use a number.");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Comments:

1. The "else if" logic is incorrect. Think about what happens if you have more than an hours worth of seconds: then obviously you have more than a minutes worth of seconds, but your "else if" statement mean this hours block

```
            else if(hours >= totalSeconds)
                 hours = int.hoursTextBox.Text;
```

...will never execute.

2. Your assignment looks backwards. Surely you want to update the corresponding textbox with the computed value.

```
             int.minutesTextBox.Text = minutes;
```

3. However this syntax is also incorrect.

```
             int.minutesTextBox.Text
```

"int" is a class and there is no member of int called "minutesTextBox." You want something more like

```
             minutesTextBox.Text = minutes.ToString();
```

4. Less important, but you don't need to TryParse(totalSeconds) if you've already parsed above.

The following is, with slight modifications, a solution.

**UPDATE**

To get a working solution going, create a WPF application in Visual Studio. In MainWindow.xaml put the following code between your grid tags:

```
        <Button Width="100" Height="50" Click="CalculateButton_Click" Margin="53,44,564,226"/>      
        <TextBox Name="inputTextBox"  Height="50" Width="100" Margin="298,44,319,226"/>
        <TextBox Name="secondsTextBox"  Height="50" Width="100" Margin="574,233,43,37"/>
        <TextBox Name="minutesTextBox"  Height="50" Width="100" Margin="392,233,225,37"/>
        <TextBox Name="hoursTextBox"  Height="50" Width="100" Margin="198,233,419,37"/>
        <TextBox Name="daysTextBox"  Height="50" Width="100" Margin="53,233,564,37"/>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs add the method:

```
 private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            daysTextBox.Text = null;
            hoursTextBox.Text = null;

            int totalSeconds, minutes, hours, days;
            int secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
            int secondsInHour = 60 * 60;
            int secondsInMinute = 60;

            int.TryParse(inputTextBox.Text, out totalSeconds);            

            if (totalSeconds > (secondsInDay))
            {
                days = totalSeconds / (secondsInDay);
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds - (days * secondsInDay);
                daysTextBox.Text = days.ToString();
            }
            else daysTextBox.Text = null;

            if (totalSeconds > (secondsInHour))
            {
                hours = totalSeconds / (secondsInHour);
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds - (hours * secondsInHour);
                hoursTextBox.Text = hours.ToString();
            }
            else hoursTextBox.Text = null;

            if (totalSeconds > secondsInMinute)
            {
                minutes = totalSeconds / secondsInMinute;
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds - (minutes * secondsInMinute);
                minutesTextBox.Text = minutes.ToString();
            }
            else minutesTextBox.Text = null;

            if (totalSeconds > 0)
                secondsTextBox.Text = totalSeconds.ToString();
            else secondsTextBox.Text = null;        
        }
```

This solution is not perfect. A useful exercise would be to add in validation, add in labels and clean up the xaml in general, or translate it into a Windows Forms application. I've added **else** statements back in, *but* each **else** statement is tied to its above **if** statement. This is logically *distinct* from **else if**.

Comment: So I am just gonna clarify that the purpose of the code is I have a text input, with four label outputs for seconds, minutes, hours and days. When I press calculate, the number of seconds in the first text box (Lets say 120 seconds), is meant to be represented in the below labels of seconds, minutes, hours and days. So seconds would show 120, minutes 2, hours 0 and days 0.

Comment: I see. Well, modify the logic as needed then. The other points should still be of use.

Comment: Actually, you know what. I just realized that the prompt is wanting something like "135 seconds" in the input and its converted into 0 days, 0 hours, 2 minutes, and 15 seconds. I apologize. I believe you have given me a correct code. It's been a long day trying to work with this. I feel fried from this course.

Comment: No worries. If you feel it solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Ok, so I tested this and I think we're on the right track. My question is if the limitation is supposed to be after 60 seconds, it's converted into 1 minute, after 60 minutes its converted into 1 hour, so on and so forth, do I need to include that input validation? I am needing to include the try-else statements to clear up exceptions. (Like if someone were to put in a letter instead of a numeral.) 

Thats why I was attempting to use the if-else-if statement, or the switch statement.

I hope this is making sense. I'm very confused and very new, so I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: I wouldn't think of it as converting to a minute or converting to an hour. Rather, you start with X number of seconds.  Is there at least a day's worth of seconds? If *so*, calculate how many days worth, then subtract that amount and repeat using the *remaining* seconds for hours. If *not* go to the hours block anyway without having subtracted any seconds. Notice that I'm not using "else" because once you finish an else block you leave the *entire* if-else statement. You can add try-catch blocks within the method to catch input exceptions. That is completely independent of the if-else logic.

Comment: Ah, okay. So yes that makes sense. I have an updated version of what I've applied from our discussion, but I am still having logical issues. The code works, but my output is nothing. I appreciate the explanations, it is helping. I am going to edit my post with the updated code that I have.

Comment: Change the "else" around seconds calculation to just an "if." Remember, an else means exclusion and in an algorithm like this you may need to enter all four blocks--something that's impossible if you use if-else. Otherwise the program works for me. If you still get nothing put a break point on your first "if" and trace the execution using F10.

Comment: I got to be honest, I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for whether it be incorrect spacing or wrong variable types. My form is just not having any output at all. No calculations are being displayed. Is this because I have put that initial "if" statement in (). Because the int.Tryparse was working fine without it before hand.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking this procedure into distinct areas - that which performs the arithmetic of conversion, and that which assigns values in the UI.

To break a total_seconds value into days, hours, minutes, and seconds, you'd usually use the (a) integer division and (b) remainder (%) operations.

(Illustrative code example...)

```
//Calculate values
days = total_seconds / NUM_SECONDS_IN_DAY;
days_rem = total_seconds % NUM_SECONDS_IN_DAY;

hours = days_rem / NUM_SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
hours_rem = days_rem % NUM_SECONDS_IN_HOUR;

minutes = hours_rem / NUM_SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
minutes_rem = hours_rem % NUM_SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;

seconds = minutes_rem;

//Set textboxes to actual values
daysTextBox.Text = days.ToString();
hoursTextBox.Text = hours.ToString();
minutesTextBox.Text = minutes.ToString();
secondsTextBox.Text = seconds.ToString();

//Blank zero values
if (days < 1) 
{
    daysTextBox.Text = null;
    if (hours < 1) 
    {
        hoursTextBox.Text = null;
        if (minutes < 1) minutesTextBox.Text = null;
    }
}
```

I wasn't quite clear about the blanking behaviour but I assume I've captured what you needed in blanking quantities down to the level of the smallest non-zero quantity, and leaving seconds in all cases.